# The meaning of "flick"

Tags: meaning

Hello: Is there a synonym for "[flick](https://cache.net-a-porter.com/magazine/413/28)" in "Transform your hair with a modern Farrah Fawcett flick"? Thank you in advance !

Comment: I don't know of a synonym, but it refers to the ends of the hair turning up or bending outwards. https://www.hairfinder.com/hair4/flickup.htm

Comment: There are several non-cognate (etymologically unrelated) versions of ***flick*** in English. One is a rare dialectal term for the fur of a hare or rabbit. But most likely the cited usage involves the "nounification" of the verb ***to flick = to jerk, turn quickly***. Farrah Fawcett would "flick" her head, causing her abundant locks of hair to swirl attractively round her face.

Comment: (Farrah Fawcett sported the archetypal ["big hair"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Farrah+Fawcett%22+%22big+hair%22) of the 60s! :)

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your explanations !